# Joining 2 Tables in a Database

Tags: sql, database

I currently am making a dynamic query string that is comprised of whatever a user checks on a html form. There is Country, District, Population, and Language.

When I select Country, District, and Population the query string `SELECT Country, District, Population FROM City WHERE name ='Tulsa'` is created. The problem is Country is in a different table.

How do I read from the City table and the Country table in the same query string?

Comment: SQL has a `JOIN` clause for this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. It's only hard to answer with the exact SQL query since DDLs of the tables are not been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both your City and Country tables have a CountryID; try this:

```
SELECT Country, District, Population
FROM City
INNER JOIN Country ON Country.CountryID = City.CountryID
WHERE City.name = 'Tulsa';
```

Comment: My bad. Posted after you by like 11 seconds. I concede, however.